# How to test a moving sphere for collision against moving triangles

Tags: 3d, collision-detection

I have a working sphere to static triangle collision detection script, it doesnt work against moving triangles though. I have a few ideas on how i could potentally make it work but im unsure about if there is any better way to do it. here are my ideas:

(All of this is in 3D space)

**Idea 1**

My first idea is to add the velocity in a linear way to the sphere and check for collisions. For example i add 1/4 of the velocity to the sphere and check for a collision and if no collision is found i add another 1/4 of the velocity to the sphere and so on. I think this is called linear impact search. If i do it that way the collision response is going to cause problems, because the triangles will just move through the sphere at one point, to fix this i think i would need to add the velocity of the moving triangle that the sphere collided with to the sphere velocity

**Idea 2**

My second thought was to subract the velocity of the moving triangle from the triangle velocity and the sphere velocity, so that the triangle remains static while the sphere does all the moving, which should work with my current collision detection and response setup. The thing here is this could cause problem with the movment of the sphere, because only a few triangles will move and the rest will remain still, so the movement of  triangle thats not even near the sphere will completly interrupt the movement of the sphere.

*Please excuse my grammar english is not my native language.*

Comment: I don't have a in depth knowledge of moving sphere and moving triangle collision. But here are some resources that may potentially help or lead to other resources. http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html (also here is sphere-sphere https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3383/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php?page=2 and https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php and https://www.flipcode.com/archives/Theory_Practice-Issue_01_Collision_Detection.shtml maybe you can source ideas from it, to apply to triangles)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.